# iOS - View Transition open and close

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, animation

In the latest Expedia app for iOS, they have a very interesting effect that I am trying to wrap my head around.

When you tap on any tile it flip and zoom animation.

Can you please help me for the same for UIView transition.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wanted to use this kind of animations in my app as well, so I have written a simple custom segue that does just that - you can even choose between multiple types of flips!

It's called *IBCellFlipSegue*, give it a try and let me know what you think!
https://github.com/IBLabs/IBCellFlipSegue

Comment: Hi iLyrical, this is awesome work you have done, but in my case in my project I am not used storyboard simple xib base project so can you please help me to this project with xib...

Comment: @iOSDev Basically, you can extract the animation code from the segue's implementation file and implement it as a simple transition between views. Let me know if you managed to do that, and if not I'll try and help.

Comment: Hi iLyrical, I have tried from my side but i am failed to do the same with xib, can you please help me to do the same for open and close animation like expedia app, here is the basic code of mine. https://github.com/googler2013/Example

Comment: Sorry for not being active, currently I'm super busy, but I'll try and help you later today! Meanwhile, give it another push and just try to take the animation code out of the segue - it will be super hard for me to help because I dont know, or see your code - so most of the "solving" part is at your side, stay hopeful ;)

Comment: I am very sorry but right now I don't have the time to add support for XIB files, but any other programmer is more than welcome to do so ;)